# set username equal to email_address in sfDoctrineGuardPlugin

Tags: php, symfony1, sfguard

in the table `sf_guard_user`, the `email_address` and `username` are requiered, but i want to use the email as `username`

so, i'm thinking to remove one of this field from the form, but as it are required, i always get the error, and i'm trying to set the `username` = `email_address` or vice versa, i've tried in the action, form, and model, but no success....

thought that writing a function in the `sfGuardUser` model with the name `getUsername()` and returning the email was enough, but no........

is this possible??
how can i do it??

thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Of cause it is possible. You don't even have to mess with schema. Just store email in both username and email_address.

```
class sfGuardUserForm extends PluginsfGuardUserForm
{
  public function doSave($con = null)
  {
    //update object with form values
    $this->updateObject();
    $this->getObject()->setUsername($this->getObject()->getEmailAddress());

    return parent::doSave($con);
  }
}
```

Comment: Updates the form object with the current values. Otherwise you can end up with a form that is referencing outdated data.

Answer (score 0):

Overriding username field in the Object::save() function is much better way - so that it handles all forms.

In you forms, you override the validator for username widget. You can also hide the widget if you want.

```
class sfGuardUserAdminForm extends BasesfGuardUserAdminForm
{

  public function setup()
  {
    parent::setup();
    $this->setWidget('username', new sfWidgetFormInputHidden());
    $this->setValidator('username', new sfValidatorPass());
  }

}
```

and

```
class sfGuardUser extends PluginsfGuardUser
{
  public function save(Doctrine_Connection $conn = null){
    $this->setUsername($this->getEmailAddress());
    parent::save($conn);
  }
}
```